# Show that $\{1/n:n∈N\}∪\{0\}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

The set is in $R^1$ and consists of $0$ and the numbers $1/n$. Call  it $E$.

Take a set of $n$ intervals of radius $r$, centered less than $2r$ apart and such that $\sum_{i=1}^n r \ge 1/2$. Call the union of such intervals $B$.

Suppose $G$ is an arbitrary open cover of $E$ and $A = B \cap G$. Then $A \subseteq $G and also covers $E$ with finitely many balls. Since $G$ was any open cover, the set $E$ is compact.

Is this correct and rigorous enough? The proof provided as solution says that $0$ is contained in an open set, and thus for $n$ big enough all points $1/n$ and after will be inside this open set, leaving only a finite number of points outside. The union of this set and those points is an open subcover. I feel like my proof is close enough that it should be correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: The set you seem to be talking about is not $[0,\frac{1}{n})$ but instead $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\Bbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$. Maybe you should also write what is your initial open cover that $G$ is a subcover of and why this would give you the freedom to make the claimed choice of open intervals in the second paragraph of your post.

Comment: Changed it, thanks.

Comment: Must be a typo: you start off "suppose $G$ is an open subcover..." And later you conclude by the reason "since $G$ was any open cover." surely you meant to start with an arbitrary open cover? Tbh i dont understand your proof. The sketch offered in the solution is the direct approach that uses the open cover definition and could be worth fleshing out. There's also heine-borel...

Comment: Yes I meant to start with an arbitrary cover $G$. My proof is basically to cover the set $E$ with a collection of intervals of radius $r$, then take their intersection with $G$ as a finite subcover.

Comment: @badmax if you can prove that intersection is truly a finite union of open sets *from* $G$ then your proof is good. You might get a finite cover this way but it could be stepping out of $G$ to do so- i don't know if it is or not, of course.

Comment: How do you know that any of the sets of $B$ are in $G$?  Sure, if $G$ contains $B$, then $A$ is a finite subcover, but $G$ might be disjoint from $B$.

Comment: You don't define what B intersect G means when B and G are collections of sets.  It should mean the sets that are in both collections.  But that certainly doesn't have to cover E.  The intersection could be empty.  You seem to be interpreting it as a collection of intersections which... well its very poorly defined to the point of being incomprehensible.

Comment: Let G = {R}.  That is an open cover with one element set. A= G intersect E = the empty set as none of the open balls are R.  The empty set is NOT a cover.

Comment: I think I get it. My mistake is that I am interpreting $G$ as being an intersection of points rather than sets.

Answer (score 2):

Proof. Let $G$ be an open cover of $E$.

$G$ contains an open set $G_0$  containing an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $0$. 
For  each $n$ we also have  an open set $G_n \in G$ with 
$1/n \in G_n$. Let $K$ be large enough that $1/K < \epsilon$. Then 
$$E \subset G_0 \cup G_1 \cup G_2 \cup \cdots \cup G_K$$ Done.

Answer (score 1):

By the theorem of Heine-Borel, it suffices to show that the set E is bounded and closed.
E is obviously bounded, since each element in it has absolute value $\leq 1$.
Now it is also easily seen that the complement $\mathbb{R}-E$ is open: for each point in the complement we can take an intervall of sufficiently small radius around the point, so that none of the points in E are in our intervall.
Hence E is also closed and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the statement directly by definition, let $\{O_\alpha\}_{α\in E}$ be an arbitrary open cover of $K$. Then for each $i\in \mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{i}\in O_{\alpha_i} ~\text{for some}~α_i\in E,
\end{equation}
and $0\in O_{\alpha_0}$ for some ${\alpha_0}\in E$. Since $O_{\alpha_0}$ is open, $0$ is an interior point of $O_{\alpha_0}$. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $N_ϵ(0)\subset O_{\alpha_0}$ and there exists a positive integer $n_0$ such that $n_0 ϵ>1$. So, $1/n_0 \in O_{α_0}$ and for all $n≥n_0$, $1/n\in O_{α_0}$. Therefore, $O_{α_0} \cup O_{α_1}\cup\ldots \cup O_{α_{n_0-1}}$ is a finite subcover of $K$.

To see this—let's take $x \in K$. If $x=0$ or $x=1/j$ for some $j\in \mathbb{N}$ with $j≥n_0$, then $x\in O_{α_0}$. But if $j<n_0$, then $x∈O_{α_i}$ for some of $i=1,~2,…,~n_0-1$. Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
K\subset \cup_{i=0}^{n_0-1} O_{α_i}.
\end{equation}