# How to show that a subset $X= \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

As in the book it is considered an open cover $A$ of $X$ but it is mentioned here that when taking sub cover of $A$ it is said that each point of $X$ not in  $U$ (which contains $0$ and finite many points) an element of $A$ containing it... But that would be infinite

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769061/show-that-1-nn%e2%88%88n-%e2%88%aa-0-is-compact?rq=1

Comment: @HerrWarum that was about real analysis not on topology i guess

Comment: @Shaun how u all learn that

Comment: After a while, it becomes second nature.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$. We will give an algorithm to select a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$.

Because $0\in X$, there exists some $U_0\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $0\in U_0$. Because $U_0$ is an open set, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $0\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset U_0$. Let $M = \lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rceil$. Observe that if $n > M$,
$$ 0 < \frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{M} < \epsilon $$
so $\frac{1}{n} \in U_0$.

For each $k=1,\ldots,M$ choose some $U_k\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $\frac{1}{k}\in U_k$.

We have constructed the set $\{U_0,U_1,\ldots,U_M\}\subset\mathcal{U}$ which is a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

The given set is closed and bounded, Hence from Heine-Borel theorem we can say  it's compact.